# Lyx preview font in the editor is ugly and not matching rendered output

Tags: lyx

Something got messed up in my lyx settings and now the editor window previews the text in a very ugly and informal looking font. The pdf output is still the regular latex font. How can I reset the editor window font? This would probably be fixed by a complete uninstall and reinstall of lyx, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Here are some screenshots of what the editor window and pdf output look like

[image: editor window]

[image: pdf output]

For context, this happened after I tried to add a lyx -> markdown converter (https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ConvertMarkdown). I couldn't get it to work, and quickly gave up. But not my lyx font is hideous!

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling, but all my previous settings are maintained, including this font issue. I tried looking for any saved files in the indicated directory here, but don't see any files. How can I completely uninstall lyx?
  [image]
- Tweaking the screen fonts options, but not exhaustively [image]
- Running "tools/reconfigure", which produces an error
  [image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! The blue math in the LyX display is not supposed to perfectly reproduce the LaTeX. It is part of LyX's WYIWYM philosophy. And to me it looks pretty close. But if you want to match LaTeX, I think what you want is *instant preview*. To turn that on, go to Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Display and change "Instant preview" to "on". Does that do what you want?

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty ! It's not just the math, it's the main text as well. The neither the main text font  nor the math font rendering the way it did yesterday. I've been using lyx for years and don't expect to look identical to the final product, I just don't understand why it now looks so much worse than it did yesterday/this morning.


I can also tell that when I'm uninstalling lyx and reinstalling it that the uninstall is not "complete" because my saved shortcuts are maintained.

Comment: Ugly in what sense? I guess that you know that  font size can be changed also simply with the mouse wheel. Otherwise is just that you slected the wrong  font or zoom, or may be that the selected font have not changed but is no longer available for the system for some reason. Your setting should be in the user directory (that you also show  in the second image). Removing it (better moving it, for security) you should return to the default settings.

Comment: @Fran The font I had yesterday looked a lot closer to the final font of the rendered pdf. This happened immediately after I tried to add the lyx -> markdown converter, so I don't think it's a system update. I'm not talking about zoom. What do you mean by "selected the wrong font?" Where is this selection?

Also it's clear that when I uninstall and reinstall lyx the uninstall is not a complete uninstall because I had created custom shortcuts and those are maintained after reinstalling.

Comment: @Aaron DO you show that you selected `.AppleSystemUIFont` to represent the roman font (it should be a serif font like times) and the same font to represent typewrtiter font (that it should be a monospaced font, like courier), but this font seem to be  very similar to Helvetica, so you hardly could notice in the screen any change of the font type. Try to select for instance `Bitstream Serif`, `Bitstream Sans` and `Bitstream Vera  Sans Mono` respectively, and you will notice clearly the difference of each type of font even in the the names of these fonts in right part of the Screen Options Menu.

Comment: Thanks @Fran,

That's maybe getting me closer, but I'm not sure it's clear what I mean by font change. I'm not saying that if I actively change the font of a document in the document settings then the change doesn't render in the GUI. I am saying that as of yesterday the fonts that the lyx GUI used changed regardless of what font I set in the document settings. The issue is more pronounced within the math environment; does that environment have a separate font setting? Unfortunately the bitstream options don't up for me on the dropdown list.

Comment: The fonts setting of `Document` → `Settings` has **nothing to do** with the font setting in `Tools` → `Preferences`.  The first is only for the PDF output. The second  only for the GUI. End dot. If this disturb you, it is up to you take care of set the same serif font for "Roman" in both menus, or two similar when this is not posible use the same (note that some document fonts cannot be used as screen fonts or viceversa, depending on if you check "Use non-TeX fonts" in first menu !) , and the same for "sans serif" and "typewriter" settings.

Comment: Respect to math font you can set a custom font for the document but not  for the screen, that as far I see is just based in the  "Roman" screen setting, so the only than you can do more at this respect is activate the `Instant preview` to see some similar to the default output, as suggested  scottkosty.

Comment: About the unexpected change ... may be you changed the setting without realizing it, the configuration file was corrupted or you lost the fonts. The drop-down list should show  installed fonts. If you do not have  Bistream fonts you can install it or use any other. The issue  is set **3 different fonts** (you set only 2) and take care that the first look (more or less) like a Times Roman (i,.e, it is a serif font) , the second like theHelvetica (i.e, it is a sans serif font)  and third like the Courier (i.e., t is a monospaced font).  Beyond here is just a matter of taste.